# How to choose which oracle client to use in VB6?

Tags: oracle, vb6, odbc

I've searched and didn't find an answer yet, I have a legacy VB6 service that needs to connect to old oracle servers (v8), we installed recently the 11g client on the server and we don't know how to force the VB6 service to use the 10g client instead of the 11g one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `home=<myoraclehomename>` to the connection string should work to select the client actually used.

Example;

```
Data Source=MYDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;home=OraClient10g_home
```

Edit: Apparently the above is only an option on certain .NET clients for Oracle. To change the used native client for Microsoft's built-in .NET Oracle Client, [just changing the path may work better.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1414029.aspx/1)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeGire Updated the answer with a Microsoft Oracle client specific solution.

Comment: Using the link you provided I found a workaround thank you ;)